# TYPO3 pageTS condition "New Page"

Tags: symfony, conditional-statements, typo3, typo3-10.x, access-rights

I am trying to make some fields read-only in the page edit form of TYPO3 (v.10.4) for users of a specific user group. They shall be able to create and modify new pages, but must not edit existing ones. I have tried this to so:

```
[usergroup("3") && page["uid"] !=0 && page["perms_userid"] != backend.user.userId]
TCEFORM.pages {
    title.config.readOnly = 1
    nav_title.config.readOnly = 1
    hidden.config.readOnly = 1
    nav_hide.config.readOnly = 1
}
[end]
```

The condition of `page["uid"] != 0` shall avoid making fields read-only when creating a new page. Unfortunately, this does not work. Only if i already have a page whose owner is the current user, these settings are correctly not applied.

Is there any way to check if the currently edited page is about to be created?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the request, which includes "edit[pages][...]=new" when creating

So This is my working condition statement:

```
[usergroup("3") && !like(request.getNormalizedParams().getQueryString(), "*edit[pages][*]=new*") && page["perms_userid"] != backend.user.userId]
```